# Python - TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Tags: python, nonetype

I'm new in python, so please bear with me. I wrote a script to check the carrier name on my 3G dongle with `python-pyserial` basically it looks like this:

```
def get_operator():   
    ID_OPSEL=('51011:XL-Axiata','51010:Telkomsel','51089:Three','51001:Indosat','INDOSAT:Indosat','51008:Axis','TELKOMSEL:Telkomsel')
    if TYPE=="ZTE":
        resp=send_at_wait('AT+COPS?','+COPS:',3)
        if resp<>"TIMEOUT":
            resp=get_value(resp,'+COPS:')
            return resp.spilt('"')[1]
    else:    
        resp= send_at_wait("AT+COPS?; +COPS?\r","+COPS:",3)
        if resp<>"TIMEOUT":
            resp=get_value(resp,'+COPS:')
            resp=resp.split(',')
            if len(resp)>2: 
                resp=resp[2].replace('"','')
                for ln in ID_OPSEL:
                    if ln.find(resp)<>-1:
                        return ln.split(':')[1]
            else:
                return "Not Registered"

op=get_operator()
if "Not Registered" in op:
    print "No Signal"
else:
    print "Operator Name: " + op
```

When there's a reception it all works fine but when there's no reciption the script returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gsm", line 639, in <module>
    if "Not Registered" in op:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

How do I fix it ?

Answer (score 5):

You get this error because you check if `op` contains the string `"Not Registered"`, when `op` is actually `None` in runtime on the particular run that failed.

You should check whether `op` is `None` before you use it in the `if` and `else` clauses.

Something like this would handle this case:

```
if op is None:
    print "No operator"

if "Not Registered" in op:
    print "No Signal"
else:
    print "Operator Name: " + op
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `op` does NOT always returns a string.

E.g. when **TYPE<>"ZTE" and resp=="TIMEOUT"**, it will (by default) returns value None.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use it like this:**

```
op=get_operator()

try:
  if "Not Registered" in op:
     print "No Signal"
  else:
     print "Operator Name: " + op
except:
  print("Error occurred")
```

Answer (score 0):

A shorter format

```
if op and "Not Registered" in op:
    print "No Signal"
else:
    print "Operator Name: " + op
```